# how to load json data in a seperate method in a seperate file in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this json file which i use to change the color of the background:

```
# settings.json

{
    "view_background_color": "#f5f242",
}
```

In my `main.dart` file i have a `Future` method called `initializeThemeData()` which loads the file `settings.json` and then places the json string inside the variable `data`. The method returns a `ThemeData()` for the app. `ThemeData()` uses the `data['view_background_color']` as the value for `scaffoldBackgroundColor`.

```
# main.dart 
Future<ThemeData> initializeThemeData() async {
  String jsonData =
      await rootBundle.loadString('assets/config/client_settings.json');
  Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(jsonData);

  return ThemeData(
    scaffoldBackgroundColor:
        Color(convertor.getColor(data['view_background_color'])),
    
  );
}
```

Inside the `ThemeData()` i also grab the class `Convertor()` which i use to convert the hex color to a hexdecimal. This is the class that converts the `data['view_background_color']`:

```
# convertor.dart
class Convertor {
  int getColor(String hexColor) {
    return int.parse("0xFF" + hexColor.substring(1));
  }

}
```

My question is if i can also make a seperate method for loading the json file and place it in a seperate file and then call this method from the `main.dart`?

I then want to just place a variable like this: `scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(convertor.getColor(backGroundColor))`

instead of :
`scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(convertor.getColor(data['view_background_color']))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial thought is wondering why any of of this needs to come from a `json` file to begin with.

It's not really the Flutter way of doing things. Unless I'm missing something here, these are just hardcoded values. So you have extra code to make that work, with no added benefit, and actually making the app do more work to accomplish the same thing.

You could just have a constants file and that would spare you any conversion.

```
const viewBackgroundColor = Color(0xFFf5f242);
```

Then you pass that into your `ThemeData` and be done with it.

```
scaffoldBackgroundColor: viewBackgroundColor,
```

Or you could put it in a `Settings` class.

```
class Settings {
 static const viewBackgroundColor = Color(0xFFf5f242);
}
```

Then it would look like this

```
scaffoldBackgroundColor: Settings.viewBackgroundColor,
```

## Edit:

While your designers are still working, you could do something like this.

```
class SettingsConverter {
  static Future<Color> getColorFromJson(String key) async {
    String jsonData = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/config/client_settings.json');
    Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(jsonData);
    return Color(ColorConvertor.getColor(data[key]));
  }
}

class ColorConvertor {
  static int getColor(String hexColor) {
    return int.parse("0xFF" + hexColor.substring(1));
  }
}
```

Then your `initializeThemeData` would look like this.

```
Future<ThemeData> initializeThemeData() async {
  final bgColor =
      await SettingsConverter.getColorFromJson('view_background_color');

  return ThemeData(
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: bgColor,
  );
}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that its a usecase to do it with with json. I have to make an app that can be customized by a designer and they want to customize it by just changing the values of keys in the json

Comment: Fair enough. But as the developer it still makes more sense, at least before actually shipping the app to production, to convert those values to constants. I'll update the answer shortly.

Comment: makes sense to change it to a const first